# trying to setup virtocommerce storefront core with electronics demo and i get this error

Tags: virtocommerce

[i get this error page when deploying storefront core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNJWx.jpg)

Virto Commerce storefront has been successfully deployed
Looks like you're missing a theme :(

We looked for 'index.liquid' view in the following locations

Themes\Electronics\default\templates
Themes\Electronics\default\snippets
Themes\Electronics\default\layout
Themes\Electronics\default\assets
It simple to fix: follow our instructions to download and correctly configure theme for your storefront.

i tried inserting index.liquid file in those folders through KUDU powershell but nothing has happened. one more thing, freshly installed platform 2.13.26 doesn't load any of each images and layout we're not properly configured or pointed.

[module layout not properly formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5ZeE.jpg)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you connect to the VC platform gitter chat to get more operative help?https://gitter.im/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your theme isn't linked up correctly. Refer to [this document](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/working-with-storefront/theme-development) for information on linking the theme (which you can download [here](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-theme-default)).

Essentially, once you build your theme solution, you need to copy the solution contents to "\App_Data\cms-content\Themes[**store**]\default" on your platform.

If you're doing this locally rather than on a web server, you can also just use **mklink** to link the store, platform, and themes together.

```
mklink /d "[storefront_path]\VirtoCommerce.Storefront\wwwroot\cms-content" "[platform_path]\App_Data\cms-content"

mklink /d "[platform_path]\App_Data\cms-content\Themes\[store_name]\default" "[theme_path]"
```